# Exclude .svn folders from getting uploaded in wput

Tags: ftp

I am writing a script to automatically upload a directory with many sub directories and files using [wput](http://wput.sourceforge.net/)

Is it possible to ignore certain folders like .svn folders from getting uploaded while using wput?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A careful look into the man pages gave me the following solution which works perfectly.

```
find . ! -type d | grep -v \.svn | wput ftp://user:password*@ftp.example.com/ -i -
```

More explanation is available at this [blog post](http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/excluding-svn-folders-while-transferring-entire-folder-by-ftp).